# How to fix Directory Listing

Tags: apache, xampp

I am setting the XAMPP on Linux Suse for my web application. 
Inside htdocs folder, I created "uploads" folder for keeping Images, video files from user uploaded. 
Anyway, when I try with URL http://www.my-domain-name/uploads, It is showing directoty listing

I have tried to put .httaccess file inside "uploads" folder, it is not showing directoty listing BUT I cannot access to files inside that folder.

This is my code in .httaccess file.

```
    <IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
    </IfModule>
```

I would like to hide "directory listing" from outside BUT my app still can access all files from this folder.

Comment: You can try by adding `index.html` file with the content like "Access denied" inside upload directory. so whenever someone try to access it directly then, it shows "Access denied" message.

Comment: No, what you describe is _not_ what you want. Instead you want to prevent direct access to that folder in general (but by placing it _outside_ the htdocs folder, not by using a dynamic configuration file). You implement access to the files using a router script only, that leaves you in perfect control of all access attempts. The script accepts the desired file name and can perform whatever check you want to decide if the request will get granted. If so, then you pass through the file content, potentially prefixing it with helpful http headers.

Comment: Thank you for you all commented. I can try with code I just use this code in one line "Options FollowSymLinks" in my .htaccess file. the result is showing as I expects.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code and it's working:

```
    <IfModule authz_core_module>
      Options FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !authz_core_module>
      Options FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>
```

Result: I cannot access "uploads" folder via URL BUT my app still access with all files in that folder correctly.